Excel Pivot Chart Seconday Axis Disappearing
I have an Excel pivot chart, used to measure quoting metrics in our sales department (showing the top 5 clients based on most activity), consisting of a combo chart (stacked column & line).
Below is the function to display the top 5.

The primary axis is the stacked column measuring actual hit vs miss values (hit values are a straight sum in the pivot table ie. =SUM([HELPER]) and miss values are a measure ie. =COUNT([ACCEPTED])-SUM([HELPER]).
The secondary axis is the line measuring related hit rate percentages
and is a measure (ie. =SUM([HELPER])/COUNT([ACCEPTED])) as below:

The problem I am experiencing is that when I filter the data via slicer on the client name field that particular entity results in no data being displayed (which I will add is legitimate since some records hold a value of 0-we have no issue with blank data), the issue arises when I clear the filter of the slicer the secondary axis (hit rate percentage) disappear and the chart goes from a combined chart to a stacked bar chart with the primary axis now displaying percentages, as below:

Here is a brief view of the data table (source of the pivot chart)

How do I ensure that the seconday axis persists regardless of what is selected on the slicer?
